# How to test React HOC function that is not passed into the wrapped component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hoc

I have a HOC like so and I want to test the `getStuff2` function:

```
function withHoc(aComponent) {
  class hocClass extends React.Component {

    getStuff1 = () => {

    }

    getStuff2 = () => {

    }

    render() {
      return <aComponent {...this.props} getStuff1={this.getStuff1} />;
    }
}
}
```

I'm testing it like so:

```
class MockApp extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello from your Mock App</p>;
  }
}

const MockWithHOC = withHoc(MockApp);

const wrapper = shallow(<MockWithHOC />);

it('Test getStuff2', () => {
    const result = wrapper.getStuff2();
});
```

But when I run this, it says `getStuff2` not found. When I print out the wrapper, I only see `getStuff1` which I passed in while rendering:

```
<MockApp getStuff1={[Function]} />
```

I don't want to pass `getStuff2` into the wrapped component because it's not needed there. It's only needed as a helper method for `getStuff1` so is there a way to access that method without passing it into the wrapped component?

Comment: are you using [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme) ?

Answer (score 0):

*(I assume you are using [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme), because of the `shallow()` you are using)*

You can use the `wrapper.instance()`:

```
const result = wrapper.instance().getStuff2();
```

See [*ShallowWrapper*.instance()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html#instance--reactcomponent)